# MySQL to Postgres syntax

Tags: mysql, postgresql, maven

I am working on a maven project and for that I am using Postgres as database. Unfortunately the database I know more is MySQL. I have the basic details of SQL file which I want to include in the database. If possible, can someone with knowledge of postgres help me to convert the syntax. One more question, for maven project, do I need to include the .sql file within the project(if yes, where). Kindly let me know.

person.sql.

```
CREATE TABLE `Person` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `country` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is what I used postgres=# CREATE TABLE Person (
  id INTEGER UNIQUE,
  name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  country varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "person_pkey" for table "person"
CREATE TABLE
postgres=#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Person 
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL primary key,
  name varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  country varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html

Comment: Hello, When I am using the query, you gave, it says ERROR: relation "person" already exists. The name of database is Person. Can you help me to drop the entire thing and start with a new datbase. I have PGadmin3, but I am already logged into postgres from the terminal. THank you.

Comment: Well then apparently you have already created a table named `person`. If you want to re-define it, you need to `drop` the old table first. This is also documented in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-droptable.html